# PostgresXL Order by error in Sub query

Tags: postgresql, subquery

```
 INSERT INTO table1 (cc, ds, ui, uis, et, st, cid, clid, lat,long, acc,
p_lat, p_long, p_acc, ec, c_tag, created_at)

 SELECT cc, ds, a.hi, uis, et/1000 , st,  cid, clid, lat,long, acc, p_lat, p_long, p_acc, ec, c_tag, now()      
  FROM table2 a LEFT JOIN table3 b ON a.hi = b.hi order by a.hi, et ASC;
```

This query prints the error that the PostgresXL doest not support subqueries. Any help on solving the query in another way is appreciated. Thanks.

> ERROR :  Postgres-XL does not currently support ORDER BY in subqueries
>   Version :  postgres --version postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.2.4 (Postgres-XL
>   9.2.0)

Comment: There is no obvious reason why this example should fail. Please post your real query and the full text of that error message. Also, please name the PostgreSQL version your on.

Comment: The order by is useless anyway. Just remove it.

Comment: I want the ordering on the data based on those two columns. that is my goal. is there any other way to do this.

Comment: Rows in a table are ***NOT*** "ordered". Inserting them in a certain order makes no sense and will most probably not store them physically in that order anyway - especially not in a distributed system. So the `order by` **is** completely useless. You don't need it.

Comment: Thanks. I will handle it in the caller of the database rather than at insertion time.